# How to get cmake style list from tree output

Tags: bash, command-line, cmake

I have this command executed from a `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
execute_process(COMMAND
    tree -noreport -idf ${DIR_NAME}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE DIRS
    )
```

with `DIR_NAME` as obviously the name of the directory it look up.

How can I transform the bash style list output to a clean cmake list ?

Comment: Is your question different from the Q&A here? [In CMake how do turn a multi line output of a command into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001683/in-cmake-how-do-turn-a-multi-line-output-of-a-command-into-a-list) We aim to minimize the amount of duplicated content on the site, where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add :

```
string(REPLACE "\n" ";" DIRS ${DIRS})
list(POP_BACK DIRS)
```

after the `execute_process(...)`.